# How can I get element html?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am using databind: `foreach` in a select element html and I want to get the child which was created by `foreach`. How to achieve this?

```
<select id="ClassNameEdit" class=" form-control">         
   <!-- ko foreach: ClassData -->
   <option id="test1" data-bind="text:ClassName,value:ClassId"></option>
   <!-- /ko -->
</select>

let a= document.getElementById('ClassNameEdit').children;

console.log(a.item(0)
```

It gives me null

Comment: Make sure, you are selecting the element after it is loaded in `DOM`. I mean your script should be placed before closing `</body>` or use `DOMContentLoaded` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event.

Comment: I don't know what is `<ko>` and `</ko>` *Knockout* probably... But you should know that vanilla JS `forEach()` function returns `undefined`. Whatever the templating thing you use... Look for **Syntax**, then ***Return value*** under this link: [MDN JS forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply `foreach` to the `select` element. As well the `id's` are unique, instead of assigning static `id` to the option (which will create duplicate id's), assign the `classId` to `id` attribute or generate some random number.

```js
ko.applyBindings({
  people: [{
      firstName: 'Bert',
      id: '01'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Charles',
      id: '02'
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Denise',
      id: '03'
    }
  ]
});

const options = document.getElementById('ClassNameEdit').children;
console.log(options[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select id="ClassNameEdit" class=" form-control" data-bind="foreach: people">
  <option data-bind="text:firstName,value:id"></option>
</select>
```